# What is correct way to send GET query with access_token to the Matrix Synapse server with CURL ?

Tags: linux, instant-messaging, messaging

What is correct way to send GET query with access_token to the Matrix Synapse server?

```
 curl -k -G -X 'GET' -H 'X-Auth-Token: MDAyMGxvY2F0aW9uIG1hdHJpeC5qZG1ncm91cC5wb' -H 'Content-type: application/json' http://local_ip:8008/_matrix/client/r0/admin/whois/@root:domain.name.com
```

Answering

> {
>       "errcode": "M_MISSING_TOKEN",
>       "error": "Missing access token."
>   }

Comment: Since you are using http and not https, why not try running a packet sniffer to see how a proper request is sent?

Answer (score 0):

I found correct way

```
curl http://local_ip_address:8008/_matrix/client/r0/admin/whois/@root:matrix.domain.com?access_token=sfldsjkfldsjflkjdskfjkdjksdmcmdsflkdsfkdsjlkdsjfjlds
```

It works for me.